# Xcode "Navigation Bar" font issue

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

My problem is the title of navigation bar won't take the custom font. I think the font works since the label and button font have no issue. The font looks fine in "main.storyboard", but when I run the simulator or install the app to my phone, the font in navigation bar is not correct. Please see the images below. Has anyone experienced the same issue?

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1. Writing in SWIFT

[Screen shot: main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OETY.png)

[Screen shot: simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikGN0.png)

Comment: Create a view with a label inside it :) apply whatever the font you want and set it as your navigation bar titleview :) thats all :) Problem solved :P

Comment: Thank you. That would work. But still try to figure out what the problem I got. Or it's a bug of navigation bar. Thanks again

Comment: This isn't the only way to do it buddy :) but easier for sure so I suggested it :) you have mentioned that you have already used your custom font with label :) thats why I said use a custom label and set the font to titleview :) As per your question of is this a bug with navigation bar ? Nope :) it is not :) I just suggested a work around :) not the only way :D Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll take this work around and moving on for now.

Answer (score 1):

Don`t you overriding font setting somewhere in code? You could also try it to set by code - something like:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 18)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1),
    NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()
]
```

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. Just start my app layout and found this problem. I thought I can change the font in the Attributes Inspector without any coding. Thank you.

Comment: OK - imho it`s more convenient to set it by code globally so every navigation bar will have the same appearance and you do not need to handle it  one by one in storyboard. Enjoy coding ;)

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried the sample code you provided, and the build appeared to be succeeded, but got error message in this line: UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "bgothm", size: 25)!]        .Received a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The only one property which could be nil is UIFont so I think you don`t have properly registered (or named) font 'bgothm'.

Comment: Yes. You are right. When I use other font. The code works fine. I got the font "bgothm" from the font book in my Mac. Need to figure out why this font won't work in navigation bar but it works in label and button. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set Navigation Bar Title Font as following :

Objective C:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"VarelaRound" size:18],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Swift:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "VarelaRound", size: 18)!]
```

Add the following in info.plist to use font in your application.

[image]

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you. This works. But I have a problem with the font file.

Comment: Import your font file in your xcode project and add the font in info.plist. I'll share the screenshot.  If you satisfied with answer, mark it as CORRECT.